# Mark method as not testable in ABAP

Tags: unit-testing, abap

Can I mark methods as not testable for ABAP Unit tests so that the method is marked as fully tested in the ABAP Unit test coverage explorer?
[image]

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? If the test coverage is 0, then it should be visible that it is not covered by the test in any way. If you want to cover it, but cannot do that because of some external dependency like e.g. a service call then hide this call behind an ABAP-Interface and mock it, then write a test method for it.

Comment: @Jagger yes you are right never thought about it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Still, in my understanding there are methods which cannot be easily unit tested.
For example it could be a method which uses some BAPI to change the statuses of the objects (f.ex. change status of maintenence order) and requires the existence of such object in the DB. IT gets even worse when this method is just a public method that contains couple of private methods calling different BAPIs. In this case one would have to mock the entire business process (creating objects, setting statuses etc.) which would mean that ultimatelly one would have to write tests to tests ;) )